# Write some lines to a file with a bash script

Tags: bash, sh

How can I write some lines to a file in a bash script?

I want to write the following into a file `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

Currently I have this working but somewhat ugly method, and I'm sure there should be a better way.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo \"\\e[A\": history-search-backward > ~/.inputrc 
echo \"\\e[B\": history-search-forward >> ~/.inputrc
echo \"\\e[C\": forward-char >> ~/.inputrc
echo \"\\e[D\": backward-char >> ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: There are always dozens of different ways of doing things like this, but what you have here looks like the simplest, probably best way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A slightly simpler method would be:

```
cat > ~/.inputrc << "EOF"
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
EOF
```

I'm curious why you need to do this though. If you want to setup a file with some specific text, then maybe you should create the skeleton file, and dump it into `/etc/skel`. Then, you can `cp /etc/skel/.inputrc ~/.inputrc` in your script.

Comment: @JonathanLin It's a [here doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). It allows you to send arbitrary text to the stdin of some command, in this case cat, and have it be processed. The `EOF` is used to indicate when the text is complete. Otherwise, it is just a cat command writing a file.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >~/.inputrc <<EOF
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
EOF
```

This lets you put the data inline in your shell script.  The string `EOF` can be whatever you want, so just pick any string that doesn't appear in your input on a single line by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `echo` command for things other than simple strings can be complex and non-portable.  There's the GNU version of `echo` (part of coreutils), the BSD version that you'll probably find on MacOS, and most shells have `echo` as a built-in command.  All these different versions can have subtly different ways of handling options command-line options (`-n` to inhibit the trailing newline, `-c`/`-C` to enable or disable backslash escapes) and escapes (`\e` might or might not be an encoding for the escape character).

`printf` to the rescue.

`printf` is probably available as `/usr/bin/printf` and/or `/bin/printf`, and it's also a built-in in some shells (bash and zsh anyway), but its behavior is much more consistent.

[Here's the GNU coretuils printf documentation.](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html)

For your example, you could write:

```
(
   printf '"\e[A": history-search-backward\n'
   printf '"\e[B": history-search-forward\n'
   printf '"\e[C": forward-char\n'
   printf '"\e[D": backward-char\n'
) > ~/.inputrc
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it.

Here's one way to reduce the redundancy:

```
TEXT="\"\\e[A\": history-search-backward 
\"\\e[B\": history-search-forward 
\"\\e[C\": forward-char 
\"\\e[D\": backward-char"

echo "$TEXT" > ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: There's no need for `$TEXT`; just `echo "[multiple lines]" > ~/.inputrc`.

Comment: And your version doesn't work without double quotes around `$TEXT` (I've added them).  Please test code before posting it, or mention that it's untested.