# Shell/Bash - How to save array to file and another file array load?

Tags: bash

How to save array to file and another file array load?

```
file1.sh
ARR=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc");
save to file2; # I do not know how :-(
```

and

```
file3.sh
load from file2; # I do not know how :-(
echo ${ARR[@]};
```

I tried...

```
file1.sh
declare -a ARR > /tmp/file2
```

and

```
file3.sh
source /tmp/file2
echo ${ARR[@]};
```

does not work :-( Advise someone better way? Thank you...

Comment: ***[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823079/write-some-lines-to-a-file-with-a-bash-script)*** is some discussion on similar questions.

Comment: @ryyker No that's different.

Comment: @konsolebox - Yes, the 5 minute timer clicked faster than 5 minutes.  I also meant to post ***[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685323/bash-read-array-from-external-file)***. it addresses the question on reading data from a file.  Thank you

Comment: @ryyker That won't solve the problem with multi-lined arrays.

Comment: @konsolebox - It most certainly does handle multi-lined files (or arrays).  Did you look?  [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7220619/645128)  and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4687512/645128) both links from the same post.

Comment: @ryyker I'm sorry but it seems that you never understood the concept. Those would break if one of the elements contains at least something like "A<newline>B". Imagine how that could be saved to and reloaded from files without breaking values with those methods.

Comment: @konsolebox - Your understanding exceeds mine, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the values of your variables are not in multiple lines, a basic and easy way for it is to use set:

```
# Save
set | grep ^ARR= > somefile.arrays
# Load
. somefile.arrays
```

But of course if you're somehow security sensitive there are other solutions but that's the quickest way to do it.

Update for multi-lined arrays:

```
# Save
printf "%s\x00" "${ARR[@]}" > somefile.arrays
# Load
ARR=() I=0
while read -r ARR[I++] -d $'\0'; do continue; done < somefile.arrays
```

That would work if your values doesn't have `$'\0'` anywhere on them. If they do, you can use other delimeters than `$'\0'` that are unique. Just change `\x00` and `$'\0` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

a.sh loads the array to a variable `ARR`.

content of a.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
ARR=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
echo ${ARR[@]};
```

b.sh sources `a.sh` and obtain the same variable `ARR`

content of b.sh :

```
#/bin/sh
source a.sh
echo "I am in b.sh"
echo ${ARR[@]};
```

execute b.sh

```
./b.sh
I am in b.sh
aaa bbb ccc
```