# Save / load array as string

Tags: arrays, bash, marshalling, unmarshalling, stringify

I have my array of arguments "$@" that I would like to reuse in an other process.

Basically what I want is a way to say :

```
string="$(save_array "$@")"
# save string to a file
```

And in another process:

```
# load string from file
arr="$(load_array "$string")"
```

All solutions I found on stackoverflow seemed to lose some information (eg would not work if some of the items in the array contain newlines or `\0` character.

It is OK if the solution uses well known programs (grep/sed/python), but not something not installed on a base system.

Comment: Can array elements actually contain `\0` in bash? That would surprise me.

Comment: Yes, it also seems from my tests that it is not possible to have \0 in arrays. It seems that the second proposition in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860477/1993501 works for me